# Appending strings and adding to dataframe column occurs "ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types"-error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

i want to append some strings and add it to a new column in the dataframe. The first code snipped works and when I try the second one it fails with this error:

```
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')
```

The only difference is that the second code snippet includes another string `_`.

Does anyone has a suggestion why this error occurs?

First code snipped:

```
df["identifier"]=df.index.get_level_values(0).values.astype(str) + df["mother tongue iso636-3"].astype(str)+ '_' + df["country iso3166-2"].astype(str)
```

Second code snipped:

```
df["identifier"]=df.index.get_level_values(0).values.astype(str) + '_' + df["mother tongue iso636-3"].astype(str)+ '_' + df["country iso3166-2"].astype(str)
```

Comment: The error says it's trying to use `numpy` array add, which doesn't work for `str` dtype arrays.  The code that works must be working with python strings where `add` is string concatenate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem what occurs the exception is the index-function

```
df.index.get_level_values(0).values.astype(str)
```

If you first add it as a column to the dataframe and then use the column instead of the function, the problem will not occur anymore:

```
df['index'] = df.index.get_level_values(0).values
df["identifier"]=df['index'].astype(str) + '_' + df["mother tongue iso636-3"].astype(str)+ '_' + df["country iso3166-2"].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar error when adding string-casted series.

This lambda solution will be slightly slower but will ensure the added values are STR type.

```
df['level_values'] = df.index.get_level_values(0).values
df["identifier"] = df.apply(lambda x: \
    str(x['level_values']) + '_' + str(x["mother tongue iso636-3"]) \
    + '_' + str(df["country iso3166-2"]),axis=1)
df.drop('level_values',inplace=True)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. the result of your advice wasn't that was I expected but it helped me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that your first case works.  But it might help if you gave a simple version of your dataframe.

Since you didn't do that, I'll have to make up one :(

```
In [321]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'foo'],[2,'bar']])                                                     
In [322]: df                                                                                           
Out[322]: 
   0    1
0  1  foo
1  2  bar
```

First look at the `index`:

```
In [323]: df.index.values                                                                              
Out[323]: array([0, 1])            # numeric in my case
In [324]: df.index.values.astype(str)                                                                  
Out[324]: array(['0', '1'], dtype='<U21')    # numpy dtype
In [325]: df.index.values.astype(str)+'_'                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-325-230387b2895a> in <module>
----> 1 df.index.values.astype(str)+'_'

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')
```

`+/add` is not defined for numpy strings

Now look at the string column:

```
In [330]: df[1].values                                                                                 
Out[330]: array(['foo', 'bar'], dtype=object)  # pandas uses python strings
```

converting that array to numpy str produces the same error:

```
In [331]: df[1].values.astype(str)                                                                     
Out[331]: array(['foo', 'bar'], dtype='<U3')
In [332]: df.index.values.astype(str)+df[1].values.astype(str)                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-332-7bc2436a1bf8> in <module>
----> 1 df.index.values.astype(str)+df[1].values.astype(str)

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')
```

That's why I wonder why your first case runs.

If I leave the object dtype strings as is:

```
In [333]: df.index.values.astype(str)+df[1].values                                                     
Out[333]: array(['0foo', '1bar'], dtype=object)
```

`numpy` converts the `index` array to object dtype (the common dtype), and does element by element `+`, which for python strings is concatenation.

Applying that idea to the case with a '_':

```
In [334]: df.index.values.astype(str).astype(object)+'_'+df[1].values                                  
Out[334]: array(['0_foo', '1_bar'], dtype=object)
```